# How to convert _bstr_t to CString

Tags: c++, com, mfc, visual-c++, bstr

I have a `_bstr_t` variable `bstrErr` and I am having a `CString` variable `csError`. How do I set the value which come in `bstrErr` to `csError`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is it not possible just to cast it:

```
_bstr_t b("Steve");
CString cs;
cs = (LPCTSTR) b;
```

I think this should work when the project is Unicode.

Answer (score 8):

CString has contructors and assignment operators for both LPCSTR and LPCWSTR, so there is never a need to call WideCharToMultiByte, and you can't get the casting wrong in unicode or non-unicode mode.

You can just assign the string this way:

csError = bstrErr.GetBSTR();

Or use the constructor
CString csError( bstrErr.GetBSTR() );

I'm using GetBSTR.  It's the same thing as casting bstrErr with (LPCWSTR), but I prefer it for legibility.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile for Unicode - just assign the encapsulated BSTR to the CString. If you compile for ANSI you'll have to use WideCharToMultiByte() for conversion.

Also beware that the encapsulated BSTR can be null which corresponds to an empty string. If you don't take care of this your program will run into undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
BSTR myBSTRVal;
CString BSTRasCString("")
char  szValue[MAX_PATH] = "";

// This will map the BSTR to a new character string (szValue)
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, myBSTRVal, -1, szValue, sizeof(szValue), NULL, 
NULL);
BSTRasCString.Format("%s", szValue);                
BSTRasCString.TrimLeft();
BSTRasCString.TrimRight();
```

Comment: I could answer should include more than just code.  What did you change/do?  Why did you do it that way? - From Review

Answer (score 0):

`CStringT`,`CString`, `CStringA`, and `CStringW`:

- `CStringT` is a complicated class template  based on an arbitrary character type and helper class templates for managing the storage and the features.
- The class `CString` is a typedef of the template class that uses the `TCHAR` character type. `TCHAR`is a generic type that resolves to `wchar` if the macro `UNICODE` is set, else to `char`.
- The class `CStringA` is a typedef of the template class that uses internally the narrow character type `char`.
- The class `CStringW` is a typedef of the template class that uses internally the wide character type `wchar_t`.

I never use `CString` in code, instead I always use the explicit classes `CStringA` or `CStringW`. 
The classes `CString*` have constructors that accept narrow and wide strings. The same is true for `_bstr_t`. Strings of type `BSTR` must be allocated by the function  `SysAllocString()` that expects an `OLECHAR` string, hence in Win32/64 a wide string. If you want to copy a `_bstr_t` that contains Unicode to a `CStringA` you must convert it to UTF8. I use the classes `CW2A` and `CA2W` for conversion.

In the following event function of a Word add-in, I show the use of these types:

```
STDMETHODIMP CConnect::TestButtonClicked(IDispatch* Command)
{
  BSTR smi = SysAllocString(L"Two smileys  in a row: ");
  _bstr_t ley = L"\U0001F60A";

  /* Either using CStringA, UTF16 -> UTF8 conversion needed */
  CStringA smiley(CW2A(smi, CP_UTF8));
  smiley += CW2A(ley.GetBSTR(), CP_UTF8);
  MessageBoxW(NULL, CA2W(smiley, CP_UTF8), L"Example", MB_OK | MB_TASKMODAL);

  /* Or using CStringW, use ctor and += operator directly
  CStringW smiley = smi;
  smiley += ley.GetBSTR();
  MessageBoxW(NULL, smiley, L"Example", MB_OK | MB_TASKMODAL);
  */

  SysFreeString(smi);

  return S_OK;
}
```