# Error in converting BSTR to CString

Tags: c++, cstring, bstr

I using Visual C++ 2008 and ADO to access a database and obtain a field value like this:

```
_variant_t vtValue;

AfxVariantInit(&vtValue);

vtValue = m_pRecordset->Fields->GetItem(_variant_t(strFieldName))->GetValue();

If (vtValue.vt == VT_BSTR)
{
  strValue = vtValue.bstrVal;
  TRACE(_T(“Field value is %s.\r\n”), strValue);    // Cause CrtDbgReport: String too long or IO Error
}
else
{
   .. other codes…
}
```

The TRACE statement for strValue will cause the following error:

```
“CrtDbgReport: String too long or IO Error”
```

I just check strValue and found it is a Chinese string with only 6 characters, nothing special. Why it will cause the error?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the definition of `strValue` please?

Comment: Yes, it is CString strValue;

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685831/332733) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

A [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a composite data type that consists of a length prefix, a data string, and a terminator, you can not assign it to CString directly as CString doesn't have the length prefix.

You can use the smart point class _bstr_t to do the conversion.

```
strValue = (TCHAR*)(_bstr_t)vtValue;
```